# wrap tables in oracle

Tags: oracle

We're having the problem that all types of people that aren't supposed to (like our customers themselves, but competing companies also) are adding logic to the database as we install it (triggers, procedures) that sometimes alter or break the proper functioning of our software.

To prevent this/make it much harder, we'd like to wrap the tables, constraints and such. We're looking to return scrambled results on:

```
select table_name from user_tables;
```

or

```
desc [name];
```

and scrambled headings on a:

```
select * from [name];
```

The data itself need not be wrapped.

Is this possible? If so, how? What are the side effects to consider (i.e. will existing queries still work)?

Comment: So competing companies can install bits into the schema used by your app?  If you can't tighten permissions/grants, I'd write something in the contract that this invalidates any form of support if somebody messes with the schema.

Comment: They can. Our customers have sys level access to the database and the schema owner password, and they're generous with it. We do have a policy that waives rights to support if the schema is messed with, but we don't dare enforce it, for fear of them running to a competitor. (What doesn't help is that a different Business Unit of my company also messes with our schema. They do pay us a fee to use it, but feel they can alter/add to it also.)

Comment: I understand your pain :) ... I've also lived on the other side of the fence - trying in vain to get poorly designed Oracle systems to work reasonably well - and because the packages were wrapped, the only tools I had were carefully chosen indexes and the occasional SQL stored outline - all because the vendor saw no great need to improve the product. To get things fixed we'd have to reproduce the problem on an unmodified version of the product, and even then it was iffy whether we'd get any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't do that.  I have seen database where all the table and column names are really obtuse like `select c153427 from t765648` (maybe SAP is like that?  Can't remember.)  But then of course you are making life hard for yourself as well as customers and third parties.

Would it not be better to simply tell customers that if they modify your schema in any way, or add triggers to your tables, they are no longer supported?

Comment: +1: treat your clients like responsible people: let them fiddle, but if they break anything they're on their own (or at least out of traditional support).

Comment: Thanks, I feared as much.

We do have such a policy in place, but as we're in a very competitive market we feel we need to pamper our customers and support them anyways.

Reason I asked is that a co-worker had seen something like this in the database of a competitor, but I suppose they just have an obtuse naming convention.